# Нужна ли запятая перед словом ВСЁ?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, перед этим словом нужно писать запятую или другой разделительный знак либо можно обойтись без них?

Вот часть предложения: **все это, а также многое другое вы узнаете...**

Перед словом **все** нужно что-то ставить? Спасибо за внимание. )

**Обновление**

Вот полное предложение:

Невероятная атмосфера ужаса, сложные и непростые миссии, неимоверная жестокость и интригующий сюжет все это, а также многое другое вы узнаете во время просмотра полного прохождения. Просто я видел, что кто-то ставит тире, другие двоеточие или вообще никаких знаков не пишут, вот я и засомневался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После ***все***  возможно поставить точку или восклицательный знак, однако изменится смысл предложения. Но прежде чем ставить какой-то знак препинания, важно знать весь контекст, все предложение. В данном конкретном отрывке, как отметил Виктор, все написано правильно.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Та часть предложения, которую Вы привели, написана правильно, а по поводу знака перед "все это" можно судить, лишь видя предложение в полном виде.

**Обновление**

Невероятная атмосфера ужаса, сложные и непростые миссии, неимоверная жестокость и интригующий сюжет - все это, а также многое другое вы узнаете во время просмотра полного прохождения. Перед "все это" нужно поставить тире, так как после однородных членов следует обобщающее слово

Comment: спс извини, что не тебе правильность ответа отметил, просто не посмотрел кто автор комента, но вы оба мне помогли

Comment: Пережили блокаду - переживем и изобилие!